# Cant set default data for choice field when using EventListener on Form field

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with dynamic choice field "languages". The languages can be diffrent for diffrent categories. I want them tho be all checked by default, so I use 'data' option for this. But it only works if I dont use Events. If I try to use it in my $formModifier function to add languages dynamically it will not work, and all languages are unchecked... Any idea how to fix it ?

Here is my buildForm function from ProjectType class

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

 (...)

$builder
  ->add('category', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => Category::$NAMES,
    'multiple'  => false,
    'placeholder' => '',
  ))
  ->add('name', 'text')
  ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
     'attr' => array('rows' => '10', 'class' => 'tinymce'),
  ))
  ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'form.save'));

  $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, User $user, $category = null) {
    $languages = null === $category ? array() : $this->userReputation->getAllowedLanguages($user, $category);

    $form->add('languages', 'choice', array(
      'multiple'  => true,
      'expanded' => true,
      'choices'   => $languages,
      'data' => array_keys($languages),
    ));
  };

  $builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $user) {
      $project = $event->getData();

      $formModifier($event->getForm(), $user, $project->getCategory());
    }
  );

  $builder->get('category')->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $user) {
      $category = $event->getForm()->getData();

      $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $user, $category);
    }
  );
```

}

I have this script in view to make ajax calls when category is changed by the user:

```
<script>
function requireReadyFunction() {
  var $category = $('#project_category');

  // When category gets selected ...
  $category.change(function() {
    // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    // Simulate form data, but only include the selected category value.
    var data = {};
    data[$category.attr('name')] = $category.val();

    // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
    $.ajax({
      url : $form.attr('action'),
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      data : data,
      success: function(html) {
        // Replace current languages field ...
        $('#project_languages').replaceWith(
          $(html).find('#project_languages')
        );

      }
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: when using `$category` in your script, are you referring to the PHP variable or are you creating a script variable? If it is the last one don't use the $-sign.

Comment: this is script variable; my code is based on [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) where there is also $... in fact this make no diffrence if you use $-sign or not, for JS it is just part of variable name... (BTW. I have tried it works without $ the same way...)

Comment: My bad, I read it as PHP code.